# Fatal error with train() in caret on Windows 7, R 3.0.2, caret 6.0-21

Tags: r, r-caret

I am trying to use `train()` in caret to fit a classification model, but I'm hitting some kind of unhandled exception and my R session crashes before outputting any error information in the R console.
Windows error:

> R for Windows terminal front-end has stopped working

I am running Windows 7, R 3.0.2, caret 6.0-21, and have tried running this on both 32/64 versions of R, in R Studio and also directly in the R console, and am getting the same results each time.

Here is my call to train:

```
library("AppliedPredictiveModeling")
library("caret")

data("AlzheimerDisease")
data <- data.frame(predictors, diagnosis)

tuneGrid <- expand.grid(interaction.depth = 1:2, n.trees = 100, shrinkage = 0.1)
trainControl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5, verboseIter = TRUE)

gbmFit <- train(diagnosis ~ ., data = data, method = "gbm", trControl = trainControl, tuneGrid = tuneGrid)
```

There are no more errors using this parameter grid instead:

```
tuneGrid <- expand.grid(interaction.depth = 1, n.trees = 100:101, shrinkage = 0.1)
```

However, I am still getting all `nan`s in the `ValidDeviance` column.  Is this normal?

Note: My original problem is resolved, and this is a continuation from the comments section.  Formatting blocks of code in the comments section is unreadable so I'm posting it up here.  This is no longer a question regarding caret, but gbm instead.

I am still having issues, however, with direct calls to gbm using a single predictor with cv.folds specified.  Here is the code:

```
library("AppliedPredictiveModeling")
library("caret")

data("AlzheimerDisease")
diagnosis <- as.numeric(diagnosis)
diagnosis[diagnosis == 1] <- 0
diagnosis[diagnosis == 2] <- 1
data <- data.frame(diagnosis, predictors[, 1])
gbmFit <- gbm(diagnosis ~ ., data = data, cv.folds = 5)
```

Again, this works without specifying cv.folds but with it, returns an error:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :  5 nodes produced errors; first error: incorrect number of dimensions
```

Comment: Possible debug route: run `train` with fewer dependencies, i.e. instead of `Class ~ .` try `Class~ some_dataframe_name(s)` if that makes any sense in your model.

Comment: I just tried using gbm again with a single predictor and am still getting the same results.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about the data (maybe the results of '`str(data)`')? I haven't seen this issue before and, although I don't have a windows machine to test with, I would need to reproduce the problem. In the meantime, try 1) using fewer trees. I don't think that is the issue but I've never run that many 2) use `verboseIter = TRUE` in `trainControl()` and see which model it fails on and 3) given the results of #2, can you run that gbm model without train?

Comment: I edited my question, replacing my data with ones sampled from known distributions, and reduced the number of trees, but am still seeing the same problem.  Is the fact that the validation deviance is not being calculated a red flag?

If I try fitting the model with a direct `gbm()` call with one predictor `rnorm(1000)`, I get the following error in R: `Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 5 nodes produced errors; first error: incorrect number of dimensions`.

However, if I `cbind` another `rnorm(1000)` to the data frame and use that as a second predictor, the `gbm()` call works.

Comment: `gbm` will work with a single predictors. When you created the matrix, R most likely dropped the dimension. Try using ` matrix(rnorm(1000), ncol = 1)` or `data.frame(x = rnorm(1000))`. Can you give us the code (to create the data and model fit) that you used to get the error just using `gbm`?

Comment: I updated the question to use the Alzheimer data set from the AppliedPredictiveModeling package, and have posted the problem code in the bottom half.  I understand this question is about `gbm` and no longer `caret`, I hope it's ok to continue this discussion here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug that occurs when `method = 'gbm'` is used with a single model (i.e. `nrow(tuneGrid) == 1`). I'm about to release a new version, so I will fix this in that version.

One side note... it looks like you want to do classification. In that case, `y` should be a factor (and you shouldn't use only integers as the classes) otherwise it will be doing regression. These changes will work for now:

```
 y <- factor(paste("Class", y, sep = ""))
```

and

```
 tuneGrid <- expand.grid(interaction.depth = 1, 
                         n.trees = 100:101, 
                         shrinkage = 0.1)
```

Thanks,

Max

Comment: I think the issue may specific to n.trees - I am getting the same problem with `expand.grid(interaction.depth = 1:2, n.trees = 100, shrinkage = 0.1)` but no errors with the example you gave.