# Can I obtain a glm object from the output of glmnet?

Tags: r, machine-learning, logistic-regression, cross-validation

I have used glmnet to get a ridge regressed (i.e. L2 normalized) logistic model -

```
ridge.model <- glmnet(x, y, alpha = 0, family = "binomial", lambda = bestlam)
```

Now, I want to find its test error rate using 10 fold Cross Validation. This can be done using cv.glm as such -

```
fit_10CV<- glm(good ~ ., family = binomial, data = winedata)
fit_10CV.cv.err =cv.glm(winedata ,fit_10CV, cost1, K = 10) # 10 fold CV
```

But it requires a `glm` object (`fit_10CV` in this case).

But the output of `glmnet` is a `glmnet` object, which `cv.glm` cannot take. I feel I am so close yet too far, because the `glmnet` is giving me the logistic regression model I need, but its not giving me in a form (i.e. as a glm object) that I can plug into cv.glm to get 10 fold CV test error.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this:

```
url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stedy/Machine-Learning-with-R-datasets/master/winequality-white.csv"
winedata = read.csv(url)
winedata$good = factor(ifelse(winedata$quality>6,1,0))
winedata$quality = NULL
```

First we run cv.glmnet, it only retains the mean se:

```
library(caret)
library(glmnet)

x = model.matrix(good ~ ., family = binomial, data = winedata)
cv_glmnet = cv.glmnet(x, winedata$good, family = "binomial", type.measure = "class",alpha=0,nfolds = 10)
```

We collect the lambda tested and we use caret to do the cv:

```
tr = trainControl(method="cv",number=10)
trGrid = data.frame(lambda=cv_glmnet$lambda,alpha=0)
cv_caret = train(good ~ .,data=winedata,
trControl = tr,tuneGrid=trGrid,family="binomial",method="glmnet")
```

In caret they measure Accuracy and 1 - Accuracy is the misclassification error you have from cv.glmnet. We put them together and you can see they are very similar

```
library(ggplot2)
df = rbind(
data.frame(lambda=cv_glmnet$lambda,mean_error=cv_glmnet$cvm,method="cv.glmnet"),
data.frame(lambda=cv_caret$results$lambda,
mean_error=1-cv_caret$results$Accuracy,method="cv.caret")
)

ggplot(df,aes(x=log(lambda),y=mean_error,col=method)) + geom_point() +facet_wrap(~method) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

You can get the errors from individual resample, for the best model with:

```
cv_caret$resample
    Accuracy     Kappa Resample
1  0.7975460 0.1987720   Fold09
2  0.8163265 0.3127844   Fold01
3  0.7918367 0.1631505   Fold02
4  0.8057260 0.2311448   Fold05
5  0.8061224 0.2777347   Fold04
6  0.7979592 0.1989498   Fold07
7  0.8081633 0.2759683   Fold10
8  0.8183673 0.3053742   Fold08
9  0.8102041 0.2474983   Fold03
10 0.7979592 0.1989498   Fold06
```

Comment: Thanks @StupidWolf for the detailed answer. I had a quick question, why did you choose `type.measure = class`? According to the docs, both `class` and `deviance` are supposed to work for logistic models

Comment: Oh it's easier to compare, the default in caret is Accuracy. You need to implement the deviance metric in caret, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23117299/using-caret-to-optimize-for-deviance-with-binary-classification (as answered by the author of caret )

Comment: I found it somewhat strange that when I use the default `type.measure=deviance`, the minimum CV error using `cv.glmnet$cvm` was 0.86. Whereas when I use `type.measure=class`, the minimum CV error is 0.19. Can we say that the former is actually accuracy? I find it hard to believe because its the output of cvm which is supposed to be CV error

Comment: it's not, see, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117732/exact-definition-of-deviance-measure-in-glmnet-package-with-crossvalidation

Comment: it's basically a sum of how much the predicted probabilities deviate from the observed labels

Answer (score 2):

The `glmnet` package provides a function `cv.glmnet` that performs cross-validation for glmnet objects. Here's the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/glmnet/versions/3.0-2/topics/cv.glmnet).

You can specify a range of lambda values to search over (or you can let `cv.glmnet` pick those values). Then, `cv.glmnet` will calculate the cross-validation error over all of those lambdas. You can then pick out the cv-error for your preferred lambda choice.

For your variables it would look like:

```r
cvfit <- cv.glmnet(x, y, alpha = 0, family = "binomial", 
                   nfolds = 10, lambda = your_lambda_vector)

lambda_min_ind <- which(cvfit$lambda == cvfit$lambda.min)
cverr_min <- cvfit$cvm[lambda_min_ind]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have been trying to work with cv.glmnet, but I am not sure if I understand its actual purpose. From its documentation it seems that its main job is to find the best lambda for the glmnet object. Therefore, it even requires a list of lambda to check as input. But in this case, I have already found the optimum lambda, and now I want to use the regularized model (that has this lambda incorporated) to find 10 fold CV to get test error. Can cv.glmnet still be the right tool for this?

Comment: Yes you can specify a particular lambda (or a range of them) to perform the cross validation on. I updated the answer with how you would do this.

Comment: Hey @RyanFrost, you should try running this code. It will throw an error

Comment: @StupidWolf, I did try to previously run the code in the way described in this answer, and it gives the error that it needs multiple values for lambda, and they cant even be the same lambda value repeated a few times as a vector - they have to be different. I am feeling that the default purpose of `cv.glmnet` is to do CV to find the best lambda, although it does also provide the mean CV error for each lambda. This makes me worried if its the right tool to do CV for finding the overall test error of the model. Any thoughts?

Comment: ok long and short, to prevent yourself from overfitting, you should use cross validation to find the optimal lambda. the best lambda you get from running glmnet is run on the full dataset. So in your situation, kill two birds with one stone, run cv.glmnet over a range to get the best lambda, and you have the errors at the same time

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @StupidWolf. @user1993 How did you calculate your `bestlam` value?

Comment: @RyanFrost I used cv.glmnet itself, over a large range of lambda values and chose the one with the least error, as reported by the $lambda_min for the cv.glmnet object

Comment: OK I've updated the answer. `cv.glmnet` is the right tool to use here.